# Reverse polarity damage

Tags: charging

I need help. I was using a generic usb charger to charge my android phone and it was charging fine but somehow the polarity was reversed. After being plugged in for some time, the phone became very hot and can't power on now. How badly is it damaged and how can it be fixed?

Comment: How did you determine that it's polarity was reversed? Getting slightly warm while charging is normal in some phones.

Answer (score 1):

If really damaged - only by re-soldering broken components by new components.

But HOW? USB polarity is declared in standard, cable is impossible to insert at wrong position without break of connector.

Comment: "Where there's a will, there's a way."  You'd be surprised how often people insert the micro-USB cable the wrong way.  My mother-in-law fried her tablet last week doing exactly that.  In her case, the tablet now shuts off when the cable is inserted (wrong or right way.)

Comment: Concerning how I'm sure the polarity was reversed, the head of the micro-usb which plugs into the phone was kinda loose and when I unplugged it, the pins of the micro-usb pulled out from the head. I later pushed the pins back into the head and plugged the phone again. It didn't start charging at once and I wondered why but still left it plugged in. @ Penguinolog, how do I know what to re-solder? When a phone repairman opened the phone to look at it, all the ICs appeared to be OK.